# flash соединение

Tags: flash, actionscript

Доброго времени суток. Не подскажете на каких технологиях передачи данных сделана вот эта игрушка.? http://vkontakte.ru/app2404568_55932879?ref=9
Я так думаю, что она работает без сервера.? Как что то подобное можно реализовать.?

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать на P2P, но при этом потерять кучу клиентов (прокси, файрволы, нет внешнего IP). В данном случае сервер точно есть. Он выполняет синхронизацию совместных игр, хранение глобального списка игроков, и хранит данные пользователя. Чаще всего такие игры делают на сокетах (class Socket), и высокопроизводительной серверной частью (java, c#, c++).
Ознакомление со списком готовых серверов (можно например) начать [**тут**](http://www.flasher.ru/forum/showthread.php?t=135830).

пс: Cам делал клиенты для игр, сервера для которых были написаны на ruby(OnRails) и erlang, правда обе игры не требовали полный риалтайм обновлений данных.